# A UITableView functions not called when B view is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I dismiss `view B` with `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`, `view A`'s `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` are not called, neither is `viewDidLoad`.

Here is my code, I'm new to `UITableView` so pardon any stupid blunder.

```
class WalletTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var addCryptoButton: UIButton!

    var cryptosArray: [Cryptos] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        tableView.delegate = self

        loadCryptoArray()
        print("viewDidLoad")
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.delegate = self

        loadCryptoArray()
        print("viewWillAppear")
    }

    func loadCryptoArray() {
        print("loadCryptoArray")

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cryptosArray") != nil {
            if let decoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cryptosArray") as? Data? {
                let decodedCryptoArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded!) as! [Cryptos]
                cryptosArray = decodedCryptoArray
            }
        } else {
            print("UserDefaults KO")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addCryptoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let cryptoPickerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cryptoPickerViewController")
        self.present(cryptoPickerViewController!, animated: true)
    }
    @IBAction func segmentedControlTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 1:
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

//-----------------------------

extension WalletTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cryptosArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let crypto = cryptosArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell
        cell.setCrypto(crypto: crypto)
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 85
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called once in `viewController`'s lifecycle. So assuming that `A` was presenting `B`, then when `B` gets dismissed, there is no reason to for again calling `viewDidLoad`, because `A` is already loaded from before and just gets shown on the screen.

To reload table when coming back from presented `B`, just add this to `A`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

`viewWillAppear` callback is called whenever the `viewController` will appear on the screen. That is the case when coming back from `B` - `A` was hidden, now it reappears. Read more in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller), specifically section *Handling View-Related Notifications*:

> Use a method like `viewWillAppear(_:)` to prepare your views to appear onscreen...

Comment: Thank you very much Milan, it works. It looks like `tableView` was loading after all but before the data was decoded from `UserDefaults`. `viewWillAppear(_:)` gives enough time now